# How to register COM objects when I publish to another machine

Tags: c#, .net, com

I have some COM objects in my C# project.  When I publish the project and run the program on another machine, I get this error

**Class not registered**

I think the COM objects automatically register on my machine as part of the build process.  How can I register my COM objects on another machine?

Comment: You cannot register COM servers with ClickOnce, you'll need a Setup project or write a manifest to implement reg-free COM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- regsvr32 "path\FileName.dll" for any non .Net com dlls.
- regasm for .Net com dlls.

Answer (score 0):

In your setup project, use `vsdrfCOMSelfReg` for `Register` property of the .dll file in question.

More [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/getting-started-with-setup-projects/).